# How to reorder labels on Google sheets chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

See the below chart that was created from Google Sheets:

[image]

I want to reorder the positioning of the bars in the x-axis - for example, move the "Over $121" bar to the far right and move the "Between $21 to $40" bar to be second to the left. The only thing that I see that's even close to reordering is reversing the order, which is not what I want to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Change the order in the spreadsheet that is the source for this chart. Afaik, neither sheets nor excel let you change the order of data directly on the chart.

Comment: The source is the list of values of data, so not sure if it will work to rearrange that

Comment: Excel lets you change the order independently of the order in the data

Comment: what if the data source is remote?

Comment: Excel lets you choose a column for X values and not choose a column for X labels. Update: uncheck the «aggregate» button in the chart settings and Sheets will behave like Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to re-enter the data as a 'new series' in the order you would like it to be.